# IllegalName: org/hibernate/validator/ValidationMessages

Tags: java, jboss-eap-6, seam2

I am receiving the following error message in the JBOSS EAP 6.3 server. I am using seam 2.3 and hibernate 4. I am not sure about this issue. com.google.gwt module is giving this error message.

```
07:59:56,146 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Failed to define class org/hibernate/validator/ValidationMessages in Module "com.google.gwt.gwt-servlet:main" from local module loader @56bbf64f (finder: local module finder @4e27e905 (roots: C:\Software\jboss-eap-6.3\modules,C:\Software\jboss-eap-6.3\modules\system\layers\base)): java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/hibernate/validator/ValidationMessages (Module "com.google.gwt.gwt-servlet:main" from local module loader @56bbf64f (finder: local module finder @4e27e905 (roots: C:\Software\jboss-eap-6.3\modules,C:\Software\jboss-eap-6.3\modules\system\layers\base)))
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:487) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
at java.util.ResourceBundle$Control.newBundle(ResourceBundle.java:2565) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at java.util.ResourceBundle.loadBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1436) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1400) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1354) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1296) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1028) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at org.jboss.seam.core.ResourceLoader.loadBundle(ResourceLoader.java:74) [jboss-seam-2.3.0.Final.jar:2.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.core.SeamResourceBundle.loadBundlesForCurrentLocale(SeamResourceBundle.java:99) [jboss-seam-2.3.0.Final.jar:2.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.core.SeamResourceBundle.getBundlesForCurrentLocale(SeamResourceBundle.java:78) [jboss-seam-2.3.0.Final.jar:2.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.core.SeamResourceBundle.handleGetObject(SeamResourceBundle.java:142) [jboss-seam-2.3.0.Final.jar:2.3.0.Final]
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:387) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:353) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.getLocalePrefix(ResourceManager.java:495) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.findResource(ResourceManager.java:174) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.createResource(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:143) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceFactoryImpl.createCompiledCSSResource(ResourceFactoryImpl.java:182) [richfaces-core-impl-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceFactoryImpl.createDynamicResource(ResourceFactoryImpl.java:466) [richfaces-core-impl-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceFactoryImpl.createResource(ResourceFactoryImpl.java:412) [richfaces-core-impl-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.createResource(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:263) [richfaces-core-impl-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.createResource(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:273) [richfaces-core-impl-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.StylesheetRenderer.encodeEnd(StylesheetRenderer.java:97) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:877) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1826) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HeadRenderer.encodeHeadResources(HeadRenderer.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HeadRenderer.encodeEnd(HeadRenderer.java:92) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:877) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1826) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1822) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:447) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamViewHandler.renderView(SeamViewHandler.java:88) [jboss-seam-2.3.0.Final.jar:2.3.0.Final]
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-3.jar:2.1.28.redhat-3]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83) [jboss-seam-2.3.0.Final.jar:2.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60) [jboss-seam-2.3.0.Final.jar:2.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.3.0.Final.jar:2.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40) [jboss-seam-2.3.0.Final.jar:2.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.3.0.Final.jar:2.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90) [jboss-seam-2.3.0.Final.jar:2.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.3.0.Final.jar:2.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64) [jboss-seam-2.3.0.Final.jar:2.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.3.0.Final.jar:2.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45) [jboss-seam-2.3.0.Final.jar:2.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.3.0.Final.jar:2.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158) [jboss-seam-2.3.0.Final.jar:2.3.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: IllegalName: org/hibernate/validator/ValidationMessages
at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:646) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:785) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
... 73 more
```

module.xml

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.google.gwt.gwt-servlet">
<resources>
    <resource-root path="gwt-servlet-2.4.0.jar"/>
    <!-- Insert resources here -->
</resources>

<dependencies>

</dependencies>
</module>
```

Anybody have idea regarding this error message?

Comment: It may be that your application ships with Hibernate libraries/APIs not compatible with the ones in JBoss (check what libs your application brings) . Look at this thread from a JBoss forum, it may help : https://developer.jboss.org/thread/259326?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Berger- Thank you for the reply.  com.google.gwt module contains gwt-servlet jar. That jar also contains the  org/hibernate/validator/ValidationMessages class. I have checked the link that you have posted. Seems that issue not resolved.

Comment: What does the `module.xml` in the `com/google/gwt/gwt-servlet/main` directory look like?

Comment: James - I have added the module.xml in my question now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this dependency in the **com.google.gwt.gwt-servlet** module.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <module name="org.hibernate.validator"/>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I am still facing the issue. I have tried this dependencies it is not fixing the issue.